# Writing an addition visitor function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, compiler-construction, antlr

I'm trying to write a visitor function in Kotlin that adds two integers together.  I've been working off of some sample code and I can't figure out what these `.value` or `.visit` functions are.  It doesn't seem to be declared in the sample code, so I'm unsure how to declare it in my code.  Whenever I compile the code, I get an error saying that value is an unresolved reference.

Relevant Kotlin code:

```
package backend
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*
import grammar.*

abstract class Data

class IntData(val value: Int): Data() {
    override fun toString(): String
    = "Int($value)"
}

class Context(): HashMap<String, Data>() {
    constructor(parent: Context): this() {
        this.putAll(parent)
    }
}


abstract class Expr {
    abstract fun eval(scope: Context): Data
    
    fun run(program: Expr) {
        try {
            val data = program.eval(Context())
            println("=> ${data}")
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            println("[err] ${e}")
        }
    }
}

class IntLiteral(val value: Int): Expr() {
    override fun eval(scope:Context): Data 
    = IntData(value)
}

enum class Op {
    Add,
    Sub,
    Mul,
    Div
}

class Arithmetic(
    val op: Op,
    val left: Expr,
    val right: Expr): Expr() {
    override fun eval(scope: Context): Data {
        val x = (left.eval(scope) as IntData).value
        val y = (right.eval(scope) as IntData).value
        return IntData(
            when(op) {
                Op.Add -> x + y
                Op.Mul -> x * y
                Op.Sub -> x - y
                Op.Div -> x / y
            }
        )
    }
}


}


class Compiler: PLBaseVisitor<Expr>() {
    
    val scope = mutableMapOf<String, Expr>()
    
    override fun visitAddExpr(ctx: PLParser.AddExprContext): Expr {
        val xValue = this.visit(ctx.x)
        val yValue = this.visit(ctx.y)
        val result = xValue.value + yValue.value
        return IntLiteral(result)
    }
    
}
```

Relevant Antlr Grammar:

```
expr        : x=expr '+' y=expr # addExpr
        | x=expr '-' y=expr # subExpr
        | x=expr '*' y=expr # mulExpr
        | x=expr '/' y=expr # divExpr
        ;
```

Code I'm trying to execute:

```
val test = """
x=1+2
print(x)
"""

fun parse(source: String): PLParser.ProgramContext {
    val input = CharStreams.fromString(source)
    val lexer = PLLexer(input)
    val tokens = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    val parser = PLParser(tokens)
}

val testTree = parse(source1)

val testTree = parse(source1)

fun execute(program: Expr?) {
    if(program == null) {
        println("Program is null.")
        return
    }
    try {
        val data = program.eval(Context())
        println("> ${data}")
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        println("[err] ${e}")
    }
}

execute(testProgram)
```

Code from sample:

```
data class NodeValue(val value: Int)
val visitor = object: CalcBaseVisitor<NodeValue>() {
    override fun visitAddition(ctx: CalcParser.AdditionContext): NodeValue {
        val xValue = this.visit(ctx.x)
        val yValue = this.visit(ctx.y)
        return NodeValue(xValue.value + yValue.value)
    }
    override fun visitValue(ctx: CalcParser.ValueContext): NodeValue {
        val lexeme = ctx.Number().getText()
        return NodeValue(lexeme.toInt())
}
}
```

Comment: `visit` is inherited from `PLBaseVisitor`. `value` would need to be defined in `Expr` for `val result = xValue.value + yValue.value` to work, but it's not, so that's why it doesn't compile (well that and the fact that your `parse` method doesn't return anything). Can you link the sample code you've based this on?

Comment: I can't directly link because it's not on the web, but I've added the snippet of code to the original question

Comment: In the sample code your visitor returns objects of the `NodeValue` class, which has a field named `value`. In your code the visitor is returning `Expr` objects, which don't have a `value` field. Therefore you can't invoke `.value` on them (unless you first cast them to a subclass that has `.value`).

Comment: Given the definitions in your code, I'd say that `visitAddExpr` is supposed to return an `Expr` object representing that addition, not its result, i.e. it should return an `Arithmetic` object and not calculate the anything - that's what `eval` is for.

Comment: How would I cast them to a subclass?  I have the intLiteral class which has value.  I changed the return statement to `return Arithmetic(result)`.  Is that what you mean about returning an arithmetic object?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t show the code for your `program.eval()` method.

The eval function would need to create an instance of your Visitor.  (You’ve done that and called it `visitor`).

You also have the root expr node in you `program` variable.

Now you would have your visitor “visit” that node and save the return value:

```
val nodeVal = visitor.visit(program)
```

At that point `nodeVal.value` will have the result of visiting that expression.

note: since you’re doing the evaluation in your visitor, there’s not really any use for your `Arithmetic` class (unless you refactor your visitor to use it instead of just doing the math, but I don’t see much value in that as the visitor is already pretty easy to read).

Comment: `program` is an `Expr`, `Expr.eval` is an abstract method which is defined in `Expr`'s subclasses. OP did show those definitions in the question and no, they do not invoke the visitor. The visitor is supposed to create the `Expr`, so that `eval` can be invoked on it. At least I'm pretty sure that's what the assignment is.